# r: readOGR & st_read giving two different plots?

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, shapefile, r-sf

I'm trying to make a map with the sf and ggplot package.. However, when I run the st_read() command to read in my shapefile and go to plot it,it's not giving me what I want.. but when I read it in with readOGR and plot it, it is. I would like to use the sf package because to me it seems easier.. Why could it be doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**Code used:**

```
NJ_Map_Road<-st_read(dsn="V:/lum/WM&S/BEAR (Bureau of Environmental Analysis and Restoration)/Envpln/Hourly Employees/KevinZolea/Rwork/2014IR/Maps/shapefiles",layer="2014_NJ_Integrated_Report_AU")
NJ_OGR<-readOGR(dsn="V:/lum/WM&S/BEAR (Bureau of Environmental Analysis and Restoration)/Envpln/Hourly Employees/KevinZolea/Rwork/2014IR/Maps/shapefiles",layer="2014_NJ_Integrated_Report_AU")
```

**Data Structure:**

**NJ_Map_Road**

```
Classes ‘sf’ and 'data.frame':  958 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ OBJECTID  : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ AU_NUM    : Factor w/ 958 levels "02020007000010-01",..: 6 81 372 59 91 385 380 127 414 417 ...
 $ AU_NAME   : Factor w/ 958 levels "Absecon Creek (AC Reserviors) (gage to SB)",..: 318 660 840 791 920 576 955 618 927 418 ...
 $ HUC14TXT  : Factor w/ 958 levels "BarnegatBay01",..: 23 98 389 76 108 402 397 144 431 434 ...
 $ WMA       : Factor w/ 20 levels "01","02","03",..: 2 3 1 6 3 1 1 5 1 1 ...
 $ AQUATICLIF: Factor w/ 4 levels "Sublist 2","Sublist 3",..: 4 4 1 2 4 4 4 4 2 1 ...
 $ AQUATICL_1: Factor w/ 5 levels "NA","Sublist 2",..: 3 5 5 5 5 3 5 1 5 5 ...
 $ FISHCONSUM: Factor w/ 4 levels "Sublist 2","Sublist 3",..: 2 2 2 2 2 4 3 2 2 2 ...
 $ RECREATION: Factor w/ 4 levels "Sublist 2","Sublist 3",..: 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 ...
 $ SHELLFISH : Factor w/ 5 levels "NA","Sublist 2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PUBLICWATE: Factor w/ 5 levels "NA","Sublist 2",..: 2 5 3 2 2 2 3 5 3 3 ...
 $ SHAPE_Leng: num  57104 140114 100002 78413 143794 ...
 $ SHAPE_Area: num  1.53e+08 5.12e+08 3.81e+08 2.39e+08 3.03e+08 ...
 $ geometry  :sfc_MULTIPOLYGON of length 958; first list element: List of 1
```

**NJ_OGR**

```
Formal class 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 958 obs. of  13 variables:
  ..@ polygons   :List of 958
  ..@ plotOrder  : int [1:958] 950 844 853 421 687 329 334 721 251 321 ...
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 190378 10574 659480 919549
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
```

**Plot I get with readOGR:**

[image]

**Plot I get with st_read**

[image]

I'm so confused!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [plotting vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf5.html) for `sf`? By default, `plot()` called on an `sf` object plots a colour map of all attributes for that object up to some maximum, around 10. If you only want the outlines, i.e. only the geometry, you need to plot the geometry part of the `sf` object. Try `plot(st_geometry(NJ_Map_Road))` or `plot(NJ_Map_Road$geometry)`, both should work.

I suggest you also look at the [first vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf1.html#how-simple-features-in-r-are-organized) which describes the relationship between `sf` (simple features), `sfc`(simple feature geometry columns) and `sfg` (simple feature geometry) types in the `sf` package.

Comment: I did not read that. Thank you for linking that. That worked. Is this the same concept with ggplot? Because when I try with ggplot it gives me something entirely different.

Comment: No, `sf` implements a method for `plot()` for `sf` objects that follows these rules. `ggplot2` implements `geom_sf` which does something different that is more in line with the rest of `ggplot2`, i.e. you don't get attributes plotted unless explicitly mapped with `aes`.